# Clear the cache if exist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have recently encountered the situation where cache is deleting properly. but what I would like to do:

> check weather cache exist if yes then delete

```
caches.delete("Prodcache");
```

something like that:

```
if(Prodcache){
   caches.delete("Prodcache");
}else{
   console.log('no cache exist');
}
```

So can anyone think of a simple way to check this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: like a specific element in cache or the cache at all?

Comment: whole cache by its name.

Comment: `if (typeof caches.Prodcache !== 'undefined')`

Comment: so caches is an instance of the CacheStorage Interface? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage

Answer (score 0):

First check if caches has `Prodcache` and if present delete it.

Code:

```
caches.has('Prodcache').then(function(hasCache) {
  if (!hasCache) {
    console.log('no cache exist');
  } else {
    caches.delete('Prodcache');
  }
}).catch(function() {
  // Handle exception here.
});
```